# Hide an element when a certain amount of scrolling has occured

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I'd just like to hide an element on my page, after N number of pixels have been scrolled.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 200){
    $('.fixedelement').css({'display': 'none'});
  }
});
```

I thought this might work, and after 200px of scrolling the .fixedelement would vanish. Alas, it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: tested and it works for me... There appears to be nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/yDVXY/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $('.fixedelement').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Shankar -- that is true. I am just showing that the code **does** work that the OP has in the question

Comment: Yes, I think the acutal problem to the user is with 200px. 200 scrolltop may not be equal to 200px.

Comment: @Shankar -- it uses integers not a string. if you output `$(this).scrollTop()` on every scroll you would see that.

Comment: You're right. I got this working. Next problem. What if I don't want to hide after a certain amount of scrolling, what if I want to hide at a specific page position. Say, 900px from the top of the viewport, once that point is scrolled PAST... it hides. This way my action isn't entirely dependent on the height of the viewport.

Comment: @Neal - I know it returns an integer.

Comment: @Neal, nice script

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 200){//Here 200 may be not be exactly 200px
    $('.fixedelement').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: this makes no difference, `hide() == { display: 'none' }`