# jQuery: Hide element after scrollTop value is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide a div once my slider passes a scrollTop() value of 200px. I've looked at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820769/hide-an-element-when-a-certain-amount-of-scrolling-has-occured) and tried using it as a template for what I want. I have the following code, but its not hiding the element. Live [site](http://www.marissarivera.com)

```
function removeArrow() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('.portfolio-sliders:first-child').scrollTop() > 100) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $('.scrl-dwn').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
 });
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated by code:

```
function removeArrow() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var slider = $('.portfolio-sliders:first-child').position.top;
    if(slider >= 10) { 
        $('.scrl-dwn').hide();
    }
});
}
```

which should work, but its not...

Comment: Just debug the value of `$('.portfolio-sliders:first-child').scrollTop()` and see what it is. It's never greater than 100

Comment: It doesn't work since the page isn't actually scrolling. Just try doing a `console.log` inside the `scroll` callback and you'll see that nothing will print out in the console.

Comment: I changed my code, since the page isn't actually scrolling.

Comment: As @bvx89 said you're not actually scrolling; it looks like you've put `overflow: hidden;` on the whole page and are listening to `window.onmousewheel`. Search your code for that, you can likely use that callback instead of binding to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @bvx89 and @ George. I ended modifying my original code and added a conditional statement that worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your whole removeArrow function with this code.
(If you open your live site, and run this in the console, you can see it's working).

The `scroll` event never fired, so I handled theese mousewheel events instead.

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function() {
    var div = $(".portfolio-sliders:first-child"),
        top = div.position().top,
        display = top < 400 ? 'none' : '';
    $('.scrl-dwn').css({ 'display': display });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Position is a function, not a property.  You need to call the function with `()`:

```
var slider = $('.portfolio-sliders:first-child').position().top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 660)
         {
             $(".Left-Section").css("position", "fixed");
             $(".Center-Content").css("margin-top", "0");
             $(".Right-Nav img").css("transform", "rotate(360deg)");
         }
```

;)