# hiding top header on scroll and moving main header up

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to figure out a way with css if possible to move the main header navigation (with logo and links) on my site up when scrolling down to hide the top black bar header (with contact information)? Website is atm.truenorthmediasolutions.ca. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you need to include the relevant code in your question so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $('.fixedelement').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820769/hide-an-element-when-a-certain-amount-of-scrolling-has-occured#:%7E:text=scroll(function()%7B%20if(%24,%3A%20%27none%27%7D)%3B%20%7D%20%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10){  
          $('.et_pb_section_0_tb_header, #et-main-area').addClass("stickyheader");
        }
        else{
          $('.et_pb_section_0_tb_header, #et-main-area').removeClass("stickyheader");
        }
      });
    });
   </script>
```

css

```
.stickyheader .et_pb_row_1_tb_header{ display:none;}
.stickyheader .et_pb_row_0_tb_header.et_pb_row{padding-top:0!important; top:0!important;}
.stickyheader .et_pb_image_0_tb_header {top:12px;}
#et-main-area.stickyheader .et_pb_section_0_tb_body,
#et-main-area.stickyheader .et_pb_section_1_tb_body{top:100px;}
```

Comment: I have tried the css in my styles.css and it has not changed anything. Is there something needed in the format? Sorry I am new with css and javascript.

Comment: u have to add both js and css